# Sweet Alert 2 parenthesis errors and phpstorm analysis

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to use SweetAlert2 but i think there is some errors because of PhpStorm IDE says.

This code exactly the same original example from Git Lib.

```js
swal({
    title: 'Giriş Başarılı',
    text: 'İki aşamalı doğrulama aktif size bir doğrulama kodu gönderiyoruz.',
    timer: 3000,
    onOpen: () => {
    swal.showLoading()
}
}).then((result) => { if (result.dismiss === 'timer') { window.location.href = 'dogrulama-kodu'; }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.1.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

[PhpStorm Complated Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVXjJ.png)

[PhpStorm Complated Analysis Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/hsazst)

Answer (score 0):

Change the JavaScript Language to ECMAScript 6

To do this, go to `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript` and change JavaScript language version to ECMAScript 6